# Windows 7 Stuck before loading drivers

Tags: windows-7, laptop

For some reason i'm trying to fix a windows 7 laptop. Whatever.

There was some issue with some corruptedfiles so i ran EasyRe on it which fixed some things, however, now when windows tries to boot it goes into a light-blue screen and nothing happens.

Interestingly, i'm able to press F8 to go into advanced boot options and select safe mode... only for it to go back to the light blue screen and do nothing. (And i can press F8 again to go back to advanced boot options again forever)

Its like it doesn't get past the boot mode selection, it doesn't even attempt to load drivers.

This is the first time i ever heard of or encountered this issue, and googling for "blue screen on boot" is less than helpfull.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can locate the proper Win 7 CD for that computer, you can start the CD and Repair the Windows 7 OS. That may fix the error.

If you can back up the files first, that would be a good idea.